# How can I modify UNIQUE Constraint in table via 'upgradeschema'?

Tags: magento2

I want to modify custom field say `my_id` with constraints `UNIQUE KEY` in custom extension table.

I have tried with this...

```
$installer->getIdxName(
            $installer->getTable('test'),
            ['my_id'],
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE
        );
```

How can I do this in Magento2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add new unique index this way:

```
    $installer->getConnection()->addIndex(
        $installer->getTable('test'),
        $installer->getIdxName(
            'test',
            ['my_id'],
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE
        ),
        ['my_id'],
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE
    );
```

Existing index could be dropped using this code:

```
    $connection->dropIndex(
        $installer->getTable('test'),
        $installer->getIdxName(
            'test',
            ['my_id'],
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE
        )
    );
```